# how is the aiNode::mTransformation calculated?

Tags: c++, opengl, assimp

When I want to load a model through Assimp library, I encounter such a problem:

The explanation of aiNode::mTransformation (https://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/structai_node.html#afa2a7210e5ba675d239f3050b03c6455) is 'The transformation relative to the node's parent.'. I created a sphere in blender and its transform is:

[image]

and the scene hierarchy is:

[image]

But when I read the mTransform of this node in Assimp (mName ='Sphere' also), the value of the transform matrix is quite weird:

[image]

the transform seems not to be consistent with the transform seen in Blender. How is aiNode::mTransform calculated?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think it is a bug of Assimp. I changed the exported file format later and there was no such a problem happened again. I tried .dae, .glb, both of them could get correct results that the mTransform of the Cube node was correct and I could render them correctly in my game scene. Besides, I tried other cases after that to make sure there was no other reason behind made the mTransform of the Cube node imported from .fbx file has those values, but the result is that even when I did not change anything about the cube I created in Blender, I could still get those values (exactly the same and make no sense) in the mTransfrom of the node. So, in my opinion I think it is a bug of the Assimp.